# 500 Server Error when setting sandbox postback url

Tags: android-pay

Whenever I try to set the postback url of my sandbox account, I get a 500 server error. Its been happening for a good part of the day so far. To set the url, I'm going here: https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/inapp/merchant/settings.html

Is there a different link I can try? Or is something just messed up with Wallet at the moment?

Comment: As of 9/30, this is still happening. Any idea when this will be fixed? Its becoming a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is probably messed up with sandbox let me check with engineering.  Does production environment work for you?  Not completing a transaction - but the purchase dialog.

Comment: It's a bug engineering is already working on don't have an ETA for the fix yet.

Comment: I haven't tried in production since the app I'm working on is not live. Thanks for the quick response.