# Reroute incoming request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http

How can I send a received request to another url, and send the response to the original sender?

I have an `ashx` generic handler and can get the sent request using `Request.InputStream` . However - that doesn't include everything (like headers). Is there a way of sending the whole request as is, and then sending the whole response as is?

Just to be completely clear:  **a.ashx** gets an `HttpContext` from **somewhere.com**. I want it to send the response as if **somewhere.com** was communicating directly with **b.ashx**.

Comment: So, to clarify, in essence, you want to create a [man-in-the-middle](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/m/mitma.htm) scenario...

Comment: Ha Ha, no. In a man-in-the-middle attack - the sender thinks he is sending to `b.ashx`. Here, the sender knows he is sending to `a.ashx`. As for why I need this (both url's are mine) - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992025/500-server-error-when-setting-sandbox-postback-url - Google Wallet's Callback url is "stuck" because of a bug on their side - there's no way to change it. (At least in sandbox) so I'm thinking of rerouting the callback to the correct url.

Comment: Can't you just call one handler from the other? The headers should be accessible via HttpContext.

Comment: @Bond `call one handler from the other` - That's exactly what I want to do. I rather not copy each detail one by one, though, because I might be missing something important.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the [Server.Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.transfer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to redirect the query to the required url?

Simply use

```
Server.Transfer("Page2.aspx", true);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that works only inside one web application.

Comment: @ispiro You should have access to the `HttpContext`.  Try  `Context.Server.Transfer()`.

Comment: I meant - you can't transfer to a url which isn't in the same application as this url.

Comment: If you need to send to another site, then you may need to look into `WebClient`. Make the request manually and read the response; then write the response to the original user.  What you are trying to do is Man in the middle.  If you need an example, let me know.

Comment: That is my question - how do I get the whole request and send it to a `WebClient` (or anything similar to it)?